# Unable to debug JNI code doing simple jarray manipulations

Tags: android, binding, java-native-interface

Note: I am using Android Studio, compiling the C code with the NDK outside of Android Studio.

The following C code:

```
jintArray Java_com_xxx_yyy_MainActivity_processFrame(
        JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray inArray)
{
    int i;
    jsize inLength = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, inArray);
    int outLength = inLength/3*2; // YYYYUV

    jbyte in[outLength];
    (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, inArray, 0, outLength, in);
    jint out[outLength];
    jintArray outArray = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, outLength);

    int alpha = 255 << 24;
    for (i=0;i<outLength;i++) {
        // just use the Y to set the B for now
        out[i]=alpha | in[i];
    }
    // No release needed since using GetXXXRegion
    //(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, inArray, in, JNI_ABORT);
    (*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, outArray, 0, outLength, out);
    return outArray;
}
```

is called from Java as follows:

```
System.out.println("Calling processFrame");
int[] rgb = processFrame(imageData);
System.out.println("Call completed");
```

Yet, I do see "Calling processFrame" on my console but do not get "Call completed."  Instead, I get

```
07-14 15:41:20.219  25810-25945/com.xxx.yyy A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x5ef78000 (code=2), thread 25945 (CAMERA_THREAD)
07-14 15:41:20.219  25810-25814/com.xxx.yyy D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 6% free 8579K/9048K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 13ms
07-14 15:41:20.299      128-415/? W/CameraService﹕ Disconnecting camera client 0x427b09a8 since the binder for it died (this pid 128)
07-14 15:41:20.299      493-784/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{413fb7d0 u0 com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.MainActivity}
07-14 15:41:20.299      493-493/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.xxx.yyy (pid 25810) has died.
07-14 15:41:20.299      493-784/? W/WindowManager﹕ Force-removing child win Window{41685140 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{413fb7d0 u0 com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.MainActivity}
07-14 15:41:20.299      493-493/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force removing ActivityRecord{41397308 u0 com.xxx.yyy/.MainActivity}: app died, no saved state
07-14 15:41:20.309      493-493/? D/WindowManager﹕ adjustConfigurationLw, config:{1.0 ?mcc?mnc ?locale ?layoutDir sw800dp w1280dp h752dp 240dpi xlrg land ?uimode ?night finger -keyb/v/h -nav/v} mLidState:-1 mHasDockFeature:true mHasKeyboardFeature:true mHasHallSensorFeature:true config.hardKeyboardHidden:2
07-14 15:41:20.309      493-493/? W/NvCpuClient﹕ Failed to bind to service
```

- Is there something inherently wrong with the way my C code is written and called from Java that could explain this error?
- How do I debug errors occurring in the C code from Android Studio?

Note: Replacing the C function body with just:

```
return (*env)->NewIntArray(env, 1000);
```

allows the call to be made to C and to return, so the binding itself works, suggesting that the error "Failed to bind to service" is simply there because the process died and cannot be invoked again from Java a second time around (I am calling this processFrame in a loop).

UPDATE: Occasionally but not always, I do also get

```
Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
```

as part of the error message.  I really do not see why but that does seem related to my problem somehow.  I shouldn't have to release outArray from the C code. Should I?

UPDATE 2: I isolated the issue: the error is caused by a memory allocation.  The code executes properly for outLength=320*480 (or anything smaller than that), but when I got to SD (640*480), I get the error I described.  Is any of my memory allocation incorrect in the C code I provided?  Is there a more appropriate way of allocating a larger chunk of memory from the C code?  Should malloc be used instead for out?  Do I need to increase heap memory and if so, how?

Comment: Not really related to your issue, but did you really intend to use a logical OR here: `out[i]=alpha || in[i];`  ?

Comment: Oops. One | is enough and I will remove the extra I.  The or here is a place holder but I intend to build an integer of RGB pixels. The format is alpha | R | G | B so I am just oring the Y with the alpha already shifted by 24.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by

```
jint out[outLength];
```

This does not work for too large an array.  Using malloc solved my problem.  If there are other issues in my code, please let me know.  Otherwise I will accept the answer and move on.

Comment: `jint out[outLength];` is probably allocated on the stack, rather than on the heap. The stack is a fairly limited resource in comparison.